# Selenium python: How to add runtime extensions to chrome webdriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In Firefox WebDriver there is function called `install_addon` which can install extensions on the runtime. By the *runtime* I mean when the WebDriver instance is created. In chrome mode, there is:

```
chrome_driver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_driver_options.add_extension('/path/to/crx/file')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_driver_options)
```

And there is no function like `install_addon` that can add extensions to WebDriver after driver instance creation.

**Is there a set function which sets chrome options after WebDriver creation or any other ways adding extensions on runtime?**

Any idea would be appreciated :)))

Comment: `ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addExtensions(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\5.6_0.crx"));` try this.

Comment: @DilipMeghwal The problem is how to give options to the Chrome Driver which is instantiated before.